# Mysql 5.6 general log file output not showing unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, log, centos

Mysql 5.6 general log file output not showing unix timestamp, so i wonder if there an option that i can execute to enable unix timestamp while logging general queries ?

**UPDATE** : Here is example for the query log

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.39-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
                6480900 Connect database@localhost on
                6480900 Init DB database
                6480900 Query   SET NAMES utf8
                6480900 Query   SELECT id,language_id,season_id FROM Episode_serie WHERE slug LIKE 'URL' LIMIT 1
                6480900 Query   SELECT shortname,name FROM Language WHERE id = 1
                6480900 Query   SELECT slug,serie_id FROM Season_serie WHERE id = 1259
                6480900 Query   SELECT id,title,image,slug,views FROM Serie WHERE id = 35 AND status = '1'
                6480900 Query   SELECT count(m.id) as cpt,l.shortname,e.slug FROM Serie m INNER JOIN Season_serie s INNER JOIN Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON m.id = s.serie_id AND l.id = e.language_id AND e.season_id = s.id W$
                6480900 Query   SELECT count(m.id) as cpt,l.shortname,e.slug FROM Serie m INNER JOIN Season_serie s INNER JOIN Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON m.id = s.serie_id AND l.id = e.language_id AND e.season_id = s.id W$
                6480900 Query   SELECT * FROM  `dernier_ep` WHERE `type` = 1 and `link`!='URL' ORDER BY id DESC limit 8
                6480900 Query   SELECT number,id,slug FROM `Season_serie` WHERE `serie_id` = 35 order by number
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1253 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1254 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1255 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1256 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1257 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1258 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1259 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 1260 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT e.id,e.number,l.shortname,l.slug,l.name,e.slug as sslug FROM Episode_serie e INNER JOIN Language l ON e.language_id=l.id WHERE e.season_id = 79 ORDER BY l.shortname,e.tartib
                6480900 Query   SELECT DISTINCT h.name,v.host_id,v.date FROM  Video v JOIN Host h ON v.host_id = h.id WHERE  v.episodeserie_id = 26605 ORDER BY h.priority desc         
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =54 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =57 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =132 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =53 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =2 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =126 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =124 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =123 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,u.username,q.name FROM Video v JOIN ooo_users u JOIN Quality q ON v.uploader_id = u.id AND v.quality_id = q.id WHERE v.host_id =86 AND v.episodeserie_id =26605
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,v.idvideo,v.metadata,v.expires,v.date,v.host_id,v.activeurl,h.domain,h.embedurl,h.basicurl FROM  Video v JOIN Host h ON v.host_id = h.id WHERE  v.episodeserie_id = 26605 ORDER BY h.priority d$
                6480900 Query   UPDATE Serie SET views = views + 1, date_vue=1532350547 WHERE id=35
                6480900 Query   SELECT c.*, u.username, u.usergroup FROM ooo_comments2 AS c LEFT JOIN ooo_users AS u ON (u.id = c.userid) WHERE c.fileid = 26605 AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.commentid DESC LIMIT 0, 101
                6480900 Query   SELECT v.id,v.idvideo,v.metadata,v.expires,v.host_id,v.activeurl,v.date,h.domain,h.embedurl,h.basicurl,v.quality_id,h.name,u.username FROM Video v JOIN Host h JOIN ooo_users u ON v.host_id = h.id AND v.u$
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Query   SELECT name FROM Quality WHERE id=9
                6480900 Quit
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok i figure the problem now which is i enabled the mysql general query log through mysql console without restarting mysql , I had to restart mysql services in order to show mysql timestamp in query log file

Answer (score 0):

Not a unix timestamp like the seconds since 1970-01-01, but you have the exact date and time at the very beginning of every line. There is no variable or whatever that you have to define for that.

Example:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.6.40-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
180723 15:21:32   157 Query     select now()
180723 15:21:38   157 Query     select sleep(1)
```

The very first number is the date in format `yymmdd`

Comment: I update my question with an example of the query log i am having , as you can see there is no timestamp like u post in your answer which is `15:21:32` i have another machine running mysql 5.7  and the file output showing timestamp like `2018-07-23T13:25:14.655125Z     11978622 Connect        database_user@localhost on  using Socket`